# How to reset UWP WebView's content zoomfactor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, uwp

I'm trying to reset the content zoomfactor of a webview in c# UWP to 1 or 100%.

The question I have is how to do that?

- is there a way to tell the webview itself to scale back to 1.0 via c#?

like `webView.ContentScale = 1.0;`

or

- what do I have to invoke in the html to tell it to zoom back to 100%?

like I would do this to perform a click

```
webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.elementFromPoint(" + 555 + ", " + 355 + ").click();" });
```

or

It would also help me if you know how to reset the zoomfactor in html / js. I would add that code via evaluation and call it.

Info: The Microsoft Edge Rendering Engine is used for these webviews.

I don't want to just reload the page, because there might have been some user changes and those might be lost then.

Kind regards from Germany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to tell the webview itself to scale back to 1.0 via c#?

I'm afraid currently there is no such methods can directly set the [`WebView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx)'s content scale.

> It would also help me if you know how to reset the zoomfactor in html / js. I would add that code via evaluation and call it.

As you thought about, we can add a Javascript function on the page that `WebView` will load, and invoke the function by [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) method.  We can set [zoom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189(v=vs.85).aspx) property to the style in that function to reset the zoom factor as you want. For example, we have the following HTML to load to `WebView`, with a `ZoomFunction` created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ZoomFunction(Percentage) {
            var mybody = document.getElementById("mybody");         
            mybody.style.zoom = Percentage + "%";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="mybody" style="margin:0px;padding:0px; overflow:hidden;zoom:50%"> 
      This content is shown for zoom in and out. 
</body>
</html>
```

So that we can zoom the content to 100%  by invoke the script as followings:

```
 await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "ZoomFunction(100);" });
```

More details please reference [How to zoom in/out the content in WebView in Universal Windows Platform](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-zoom-inout-the-2fcce768).

Comment: The link in here is dead and redirects to the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=MSDN-samples